# Linux Command Outputs Terminated Processes

Tags: c, linux, process, exec, ps

I'm working in C and using the following code to execute the `ps` linux command:

```
char *const parmList[] = {"ps","-o","pid","-g",processGroupID,NULL};
execvp(parmList[0], parmList);
```

The problem is that it prints all the processes from the group including ones that have been terminated. I need to make sure that the group processes that have **NOT** been terminated are the only ones shown. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `a x r` options to get only running processes.

Answer (score 1):

`ps` command display's the list of active processes of that current tty terminal.

`ps - axrgo pid` or `ps -axro pid -g`

`ps` has an simple process selection option.

`-a` ------->      Select all processes except both session leaders and           processes not associated with a terminal. i.e includes all active terminals

`-e` ------->     Includes all processes.

`-g` ------->     Select by session OR by effective group name.

`-r` ------->     Restrict the selection to only running processes.

`-x` ------->     option causes ps to list all processes owned by you   (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a option.

Comment: Is there anyway to show both running and suspended ones but not terminated ones?